# Using a C# Socket both ways

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, c#-4.0, tcp

I have a simple C# Windows Presentation Framework program, which spawns a TCP Listener. This TCP Listener accepts a socket from a connection, which I then want to be able to receive and send data on.

I wasn't sure how to do that with the same socket, so I setup this loop.

Essentially at the start of every loop, checking with a timeout (I think is 10 ms) for new data, then regardless of new data proceding to send data if applicable. If I didn't have the timeout, I couldn't send data without first recieving data, as calling socket.recieve would block until we had something.

However, having this timeout causes horrible lag with my application. Despite operating in a different frame! From testing, as soon as I remove the timeout, the lag goes away. So I am fairly confident that is the issue.

This leads me to thinking, is this the wrong way to be doing this? Should I be utilizing that Async Receive call instead? I didn't think that was the solution but I am not sure.  Is there a better way to do this? I guess purposefully throwing this exception is very bad for performance.

```
    System.Net.IPAddress localAddr = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1);
    TcpListener mListener = new TcpListener(localAddr, 5000);
    var thread = new System.ThreadingThread(() => {
        mListener.Start();

        //Loop Forever
        mListener.Start();

        while(true){

           Socket client = mListener.AcceptSocket();

               client.ReceiveTimeout = 10;

                while(true){
            byte[] data = new byte[5000];       

            int returnsize = 0;
            try{
                  returnSize = client.Recieve(data);
            }catch(Exception e){
              //Client Timeout!
                  //We will catch a data on the next loop
            }

            //now here I would check here if a queue has data to send
            //if so use client.send

            //proceed to next loop
            }

        }

    });
thread.Start();
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: _"is this the wrong way to be doing this? Should I be utilizing that Async Receive call instead?"_ -- yes, this is the wrong way. I/O should never be handled with polling. And yes, async I/O is a much better approach, for a wide variety of reasons. The .NET socket support has a number of different async APIs to choose from, all of which work well. Modern code should probably use `NetworkStream` to wrap the socket, or use the `TaskFactory.FromAsync()` method, so that `async`/`await` can be used. Please do some research, and post a question only when you have something _specific_ to ask.

Comment: You can use something like SignalR, instead of reinventing the wheel for duplex communication.

Comment: +1 to SignalR, I've used it in many projects. Nice thing about it is that it will use WebSockets when available, and simulate them with long-polling when not.